# When I try to send a email in spring boot I get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/Provider

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror

I have developing a user registration. When user enter the details he get an email OTP to his given mail. This working fine in localhost. So I put the application in server and send a post request to the server. Data is saving successfully, But I get a error when email sending. The error I get is,

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/Provider
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:964) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
> at javax.mail.Session.(Session.java:254) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
> at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:298) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
> at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.getSession(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:163) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at lk.exon.miracle_island.service.impl.BuyerServicesImpl.sendEmailWithTemplate(BuyerServicesImpl.java:174) ~[classes/:0.0.1]
> at lk.exon.miracle_island.service.impl.BuyerServicesImpl.buyerRegistration(BuyerServicesImpl.java:125) ~[classes/:0.0.1]
> at lk.exon.miracle_island.controller.BuyerController.buyerRegistration(BuyerController.java:20) ~[classes/:0.0.1]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at lk.exon.miracle_island.security.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:79) ~[classes/:0.0.1]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_352]
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.mail.Provider
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
> ... 125 common frames omitted

I searched solutions and also added Jakartha mail dependency too.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

After that, in local host it works fine. But not in the server. Anyone can help on this?

Comment: Your error message is far too long and far too hard to read. I don't think we need the entire stack trace; just the first part, and the section of code from which the error is being thrown, will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This Happened because I used the newest version of jakarta mail. In newest version there is class and when it looking for newest version is can not find for the relevant class